# How to use a decorator to log all function calls from a particular module?

Tags: python, arcpy

**Some background:**

I am trying to write a decorator for logging. Specifically, I work with `arcpy` a lot and the way to get messages back from tools is to use `arcpy.GetMessages()`. However, this is kind of an annoying function because it only holds the most recent message and must be called after every tool. A pseudo-code example

```
import arcpy
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_function(in_data):
    out_data = 'C:/new_path/out_data'
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_data, out_data)
    log.info(arcpy.GetMessages())

    arcpy.Delete_management(in_data)
    log.info(arcpy.GetMessages()) 

    # If you did log.info(arcpy.GetMessages()) again here you'd just get 
    # the message from the Delete tool again
```

It would be much better to write a decorator that could identify any time an `arcpy` function was called and log it. Like:

```
def log_the_arcpy(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        # Some magic happens here?!
        if module_parent == arcpy: #module_parent is obviously fake, is there a real attribute?
            log.info(arcpy.GetMessages())
        return result
    return inner
```

**However, I am quite stuck in two places:** (1) how to identify the "arcpy-ness" (or whatever package) of an individual function, and (2) the overall approach to dig inside of a function with a decorator and determine the package membership of potentially many function calls.

Bits and pieces that have *seemed* useful are:

- using `hasattr` (but doesn't seem quite right/maybe very slow?)
- using reflection (like this [great blog post did to log a function's local variables upon exit](http://scottlobdell.me/2015/08/taking-logging-next-level-python/)) or
- some magic using `inspect` and/or a generator to pause execution

None of these are ideas that are very well fleshed out - this because many of these topics are quite new to me. I would appreciate any direction - I'm trying to ask early so I don't get locked into asking a bunch of [XY Problem questions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be calling methods directly on `arcpy`, wrapping the module would probably be the easiest and least performance-affecting approach:

```
# arcpy_proxy.py
import arcpy as _arcpy
import logging

class _proxy(object):

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        ref = getattr(_arcpy, item)
        if callable(ref):  # wrap only function calls
            return self._wrap(ref)
        return ref

    @classmethod
    def _wrap(cls, func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            val = func(*args, **kwargs)
            logging.info(_arcpy.GetMessages())  # log the messages
            return val
        return inner

arcpy = _proxy()
```

Then you can just do `from arcpy_proxy import arcpy` as a drop-in replacement. You can even add `sys.modules["arcpy"] = arcpy` in your main script (after the import of course) so you don't have to replace it anywhere else to have it proxied.

Comment: @HFBrowning - gotta sacrifice something for convenience ;) As long as you don't replace `sys.modules["arcpy"]` with it, you have full control which parts of your code would use the wrapper and which wouldn't (you can even have them both in the global namespace and use each as the need arises) so it doesn't differ in any shape or form from manually adding decorators, except that it's far more convenient.

Comment: This worked unbelievably well. So grateful I didn't have to go on a 2-week hunt to learn about generators, reflection, and the inspect package. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if hasattr(fn, '__module__') and getattr(fn, '__module__') == 'arcpy':
    log.info(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Full function:

```
def log_the_arcpy(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(fn, '__module__') and getattr(fn, '__module__') == 'arcpy':
            log.info(arcpy.GetMessages())
        return result
    return inner
```

Comment: Sorry to be dense - could you work it into something similar to my second code sample? I am pretty new to decorators too so I'm not certain where this goes exactly - since my brain thinks of `fn` as being the whole function and it's hard to understand how to test for `'__module__' == 'arcpy'` for all functions *inside* `fn`

Comment: Please try it out.

Comment: It's not working - I think because `fn` isn't in module `arcpy` (I'm using a trivial function I wrote that is similar to the `test_function()` in my example - if it wasn't clear, I want to decorate function that I wrote that include `arcpy` inside of them). This is giving me some ideas though about how I might test the function calls inside of `fn/test_function`...